# Cloud Build fail a build conditionally

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

Working on setting up a CI pipeline with GCP Cloud Build for cloud functions. Our organization likes using Behave for testing python, so I'm trying to do the following with Cloud Build:

1. Run behave tests using functions-framework
2. Upload the results of those tests to a bucket
3. IF the tests succeeded, deploy the function to our test environment

As-is, the only part not working is the IF in step 3. The function is deployed regardless of whether the behave tests succeed. I believe because I'm piping the results, and the writing of the results is succeeding. I'd like steps 1 and 2 to always run, and if the behave tests failed, skip step 3 and fail the build.

I tried saving the exit code of the tests using `[ 0 -eq ${PIPESTATUS[0]} ]` at the end of the command string in the first step, but I'm unable how to use that value to achieve what I've described above.

The contents of my cloudbuild.yaml file:

```
steps:
  - id: 'run-behave-tests'
    name: 'gcr.io/my-project/my-docker-image:v1'
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    args: [-c, 'pip install -r ./gcfs/hello/requirements.txt && cd ./gcfs/hello && (functions-framework --target=hello --signature-type=http --port=8080) & sleep 10 && cd ./gcfs/hello && behave --tags=local --format json --no-skipped --no-source --no-summary | jq ''.[] |= {"function_name": "hello"} + .'' | jq -c ".[]" > /workspace/behave_output_hello.json']
  - id: 'upload-behave-results'
    name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    args:
      - gcloud
      - storage
      - cp
      - --content-type=text/plain
      - /workspace/behave_output_hello.json
      - gs://bucketbucketbucket/behave_output.json
  - id: 'deploy-function'
    name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    args:
      - gcloud
      - functions
      - deploy
      - function-name
      - --region=us-central1
      - --source=https://MYCLOUDREPO/revisions/dev/paths/gcfs/hello
      - --trigger-http
      - --runtime=python311
      - --project=myproject
options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
```

The "my-docker-image" dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11
RUN pip install behave
RUN pip install requests
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install sudo
RUN sudo apt-get install jq -y
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you think it might be possible to develop some conditional logic by using a bash script inside the yaml file?

If that is feasible - the last step of the yaml file might look as:

```
- id: "some identifier"
  name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
    - '-c'
    - |

      if [[ -z "${example}" ]] 
      then
        echo "deploy the cloud function using your preferred method"
      else
        echo "don't deploy the cloud function"
      fi
```

In case you need to transfer any data between steps (i.e. some test results), you may like to save that data in a local (for the Cloud Build runtime) file in one step, and read it in a subsequent step.

```
echo ${some_data} > /workspace/some_data_file

some_data=$(cat /workspace/some_data_file)
```